# How to add nested path aliases in vscode jsconfig?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-jsconfig

### Background

I have a config like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "common": ["./common/*"],
      "components": ["./components/*"],
      "services": ["./services/*"],
      "styles": ["./styles/*"],
      "state": ["./state/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["ES5"]
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

Focusing only on the `components` directory, the structure is:

```
components/shared/*
```

because of which, to import a shared file, I have to write:

```js
import File from "components/shared/file"
```

### Question

How should I modify the jsconfig so that I will be able to directly import from the shared folder like:

```js
import File from "shared/file"
```

Comment: maybe adding `"shared":["./components/shared/*"]` to the paths?

Comment: @AlanOmar Tried this but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to change the json `baseUrl` like this way -

```
"baseUrl": "./src/components"
```

But this is not the appropriate way to use baseUrl. Because after using this setting all of your import will be according to `components` folder. And this is not actually base url.

Comment: Agreed. So I guess there's no simple option to do what I want.

Comment: You have to use `"baseUrl": "./src"` like this. So you can get all paths easily according to src.